# Bootstrap 4 - How do set it so the menu always starts scrolled to the top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, scroll

example:
https://codepen.io/jgritten/pen/zpPrdE

If you open the example, expand the dropdown menu, scroll somewhere down the list and close it. When you reopen the list, its still scrolled to where you left it. How do I set it so this always opens scrolled to the top?

thanks

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It can be done with JavaScript. BootStrap triggers events when the dropdown is open/closed. You could reset the scroll position before the dropdown is displayed.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the below jQuery code to fix this issue.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').scrollTop(0);
})
```

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').scrollTop(0);
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  font: 13px Verdana;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.btn.btn-primary,
.dropdown li a {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dropdown li a {
  padding: 4px 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">18</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thx. Didn't use this exactly but it lead to my answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted BhuwanBhatt's answer because it lead to the answer I needed. In my particular case and my project being Angular with Typescript components I attached a click function with the code...

```
document.getElementById('menu_container').scrollTop = 0;
```

Thanks for the help.